# mwe2 reference workflow

Tags: eclipse

When you start a new Eclipse IDE and create a new MWE2 workflow you can reference workflows from plugins in the target environment or workspace (within new RCP)

`component = @foo.MyWorkflow {}`

But this doesn't works for all workflows, some aren't resolvable:

```
Couldn't resolve reference to Module 'OtherWorkflow'.
```

Even when copying `MyWorkflow`, renaming to `MyWorkflow2` and restarting the RCP: `MyWorkflow2` isn't resolvable.

edit: must be some kind of problem of the xtext referencer, after some time without any changes, also other workflows can be resolved, but after deleting the workspace of the RCP they re-disappear
edit2: appears like a bug in 2.3.1, with latest nightly (pre 2.4) all workflows can be resolved

Answer (score 0):

First: The @ notation does not require a second eclipse instance. The editor and tooling also resolves in the *same* instance.

Second: The mwe2 builder is not very reliable. Have a look at the hidden `bin` folder within your project space. The builder should copy and update your mwe2 files in this location. It will only reference files that are present and up-to-date here. I found that I often had to touch the source files to force a rebuild, or to delete the target files to get rid of a stale state that was not recognized.

Otherwise mwe2 is a sparsely charted meta-black hole. You have your wits. Good luck.

Comment: Also, you may want to check this list of mwe trouble causes, some of which are not obvious: http://jevopisdeveloperblog.blogspot.de/2011/06/when-your-mwe2-workflow-is-not-working.html

Comment: I only had this problem in a second instance (and therefore in another workspace). I know that with the `bin/` folder but this is a good hint for others.